# ConstraintLayout relative to ImageView dimensions

Tags: android, android-custom-view, vector-graphics, android-constraintlayout

I'm currently developing a small Android application and use the new ConstraintLayout.

I have an ImageView which contains a vector graphic image which is supposed to take the maximum space available with respect to its aspect ratio. I got this to work with the following code:

```xml
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin"
    android:src="@drawable/image"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    />
```

Now, I want to place multiple custom views (buttons) at exact positions. Using Constraint Guidelines, I came up with the following:

```xml
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline_x"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.20"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="..."
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="..."
    />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline_y"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.20"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="..."
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="..."
    />

<com.example.android.myCustomView
    android:id="@+id/myCustomView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="doSomething"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline_x"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline_y"
    />
```

This works great for the specific device that I've been testing with initially. But: As soon as the device dimensions vary, the custom views are placed at wrong positions.

I am looking for a way to place a custom view n% relative to the x coordinate of the image view. I've tried adding `app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView"` to the guidelines but this changes nothing. Do you have any ideas how I can resolve this issue? Thanks a lot!

Edit:
Here are 2 images which illustrate the issue.

Samsung Galaxy S8:
[image: Samsung Galaxy S8]

Google Pixel XL:
[image: Google Pixel XL]

The little red square should always be at the exact same position relative to the Android icon.

Comment: Use percent dimensions feature of `ConstraintLayout`, you can use it for both width and height. `android:layout_width="0dp"
app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".4"`. Here .4 is 40%.

Comment: @Tim Can you share what the screen looks like on your device vs on other devices?

Comment: @LalitSinghFauzdar Where should I set `app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".4"`?

Comment: @AjilO. Sorry I can't... this would leak too much information about the apps content...

Comment: @Tim You should set this in your CustomView with left and right of your CustomView constrained to left and right of the parent.

Comment: @AjilO. I've build a test case which allowed me to create some screenshots. See my initial post above.

Comment: @LalitSinghFauzdar The parent is set to `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and `android:layout_height="match_parent"` - do you want me to change that? If I set it to `wrap_content` (or something else), the image is no longer scaled to its maximum size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a easier way to place a widget precisely on an `ImageView` or any other view that will retain it placement regardless of any change in size of the `ImageView` as long as the aspect ratio remains constant. In the first proposed solution of my other answer, I suggested using bias to place the widget within the `ImageView`. Unfortunately, a change in the relative size of the widget to to the size of the `ImageView` causes the widget to shift on the image which is not desireable.

To get around this, I suggest placing a 1x1 pixel `Space` view on the `ImageView` using bias. Because the Space view is just 1x1 pixel in size, it can be placed anywhere within the `ImageView` by using bias. It's relative position will remain constant as the `ImageView` changes size due to rotation on a single device or because the app is being hosted on devices with different screen sizes. It is just important that the aspect ratio of the image remain constant regardless of the size of the screen.

Once the 1x1 pixel view is placed, the widget can be attached through constraints. In the example below, I have chosen to center the widgets for the eyes on the placement pixels by constraining all sides of each eye widget to the corresponding sides of its placement pixel.

Here are some images showing the effect. Screen with varying sizes that I have tested show the same result.

**Nexus 6 Portrait**

[image: Nexus 6 Portrait]

**Nexus 6 Landscape**

[image]

Because the `ImageView`s for the eyes are not scaled, they appear smaller on the Nexus 10 screen. The eyes are placed in the same location as on the Nexus 6. Scaling the eyes is a different matter.

**Nexus 10 Landscape**

[image]

Here is the layout showing the constraints:

[image]

**position_view.xml**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/androidGreen"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/android_image"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/pinpoint1"
        android:layout_width="1px"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/androidGreen"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/androidGreen"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.373"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/androidGreen"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/androidGreen"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.19" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/circle"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/pinpoint1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/pinpoint1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/pinpoint1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/pinpoint1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/circle"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/pinpoint2"
        android:layout_width="1px"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/androidGreen"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/androidGreen"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.625"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/androidGreen"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/androidGreen"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.19" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/circle"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/pinpoint2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/pinpoint2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/pinpoint2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/pinpoint2"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

You can also achieve the same goal by wrapping the `ImageView` in a `ConstraintLayout` and setting the width and height of the `ImageView` to `match_parent`. You can then use percent guidelines to position a widget on the `ImageView`. This method introduces another level in the layout hierarchy but may be easier to understand.

Here is XML that will demonstrate this method.

**XML using guidelines within nested `ConstraintLayout`**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/androidGreen"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/android_image"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guidelineHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.19" />

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guidelineVerticalLeft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.375" />

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guidelineVerticalRight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.625" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/circle"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guidelineHorizontal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guidelineVerticalLeft"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guidelineVerticalLeft"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guidelineHorizontal"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/circle"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/circle"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guidelineHorizontal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guidelineVerticalRight"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guidelineVerticalRight"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guidelineHorizontal"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Great solution. Can you update the image with one that shows the Constraint lines?

Comment: I just tried the second part of this solution and it works great! I only had to change `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"` to `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"` - otherwise I would have to scroll in landscape mode. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Tim That's really the way to go. The other methods, although OK, have subtle issues.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to position a view within another view, take a look at [Centering positioning and bias](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html#CenteringPositioning) in `ConstraintLayout`.

> **Bias**
>
> The default when encountering such opposite constraints is to center the widget; but you can tweak the positioning to favor one side over another using the bias attributes:

Here is a `TextView` positioned 20% from the left side of the image and 70% from the top. The positioning will remain constant with different screen sizes, but you will have to make sure the aspect ratio stays constant; otherwise, the `TextView` will drift.

[image]

Here is the XML for the image above:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_android_green_24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView here"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.7" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Another way to handle positioning within a view that provides more precise targeting is to define a horizontal and vertical chain of `Space` views that use weights to divide up the container view. Here is the same layout as above but with a vertical boundary between two `Space` views at 20% of the width of the `ImageView`. An additional two `Space` views have a horizontal boundary at 70% of the container view. See [Chains](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html#Chains) in the documentation for `ConstraintLayout`.

[image]

Here is the XML:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_android_green_24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/space1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/space2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="20"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imageView" />

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/space2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="80"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/space1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imageView" />

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/space3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/space4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="70" />

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/space4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/space3"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="30" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView here"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/space1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/space3" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed response! Sorry for not verifying it 100% earlier. I just took a look and sadly, the first approach doesn't work... The positions on a Samsung Galaxy S8 and a Pixel XL differ. Rotating the device mode shows the issue even with a single device. I've updated the initial post with 2 images that show the problem. 
I haven't tested the second approach. In my case, this would be a lot of work as I have to position multiple points independently with rather obscure positions (something like `0.2214112`). Hopefully there is an easier (and working) solution.

Comment: @Tim You could divide up the image using chains but I don't know if it is as precise as 0.2214112. You could also do this programmatically which is where I think this is heading. Would you be open to such a solution? How many point would you have to map?

Comment: This would be ok, yes. At the moment, I have to position 5 of them.

Comment: @Tim I posted another answer after my comment. The second answer is the way to go if you want to use XML. If doing this programatically, you will need to use [`ConstraintSet`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintSet.html).