# How to add dot on specific position of ImageView in the Constraintlayout

Tags: java, android, android-constraintlayout

I like to add Button which connect by line to green dot at specific position of ImageView in the ConstraintLayout.
But the green dot specific position can not be fixed when Image Scale on different screen or rotation. Please refer to photo.

Currently, I try to add some Green dot(View with drawable background). And control their position by constraintHorizontal_bias and constraintVertical_bias. But it not works fine.

```
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.59"
app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.788"
```

The codes are like below:

```
   <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button_oobe_1p7_ok"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_oobe_1p7_title2"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/icon_body_w" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="3dp"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_bodypart_dot_selected"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.561"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.501" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="3dp"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_bodypart_dot_selected"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.095" />


    <View
        android:id="@+id/view3"
        android:layout_width="3dp"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_bodypart_dot_selected"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.59"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.788" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I don't know what you want to achieve. Could you please explain more precisely?

Comment: Hi Prexx, thanks for your question. I like to add a button which connect to a green dot by a line. You could reference to photo:https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeeQc.png

Comment: Because ImageView will scale on different screen, so I don’t know how to design it.

Comment: So you already added the dots (which work fine on different screens) and now you want to add the lines with Buttons for each dot?

Comment: Sorry for unclear and wrong description. My question is how to add a green dot on specific position of ImageView. If I can complete dots part, line and button should be not a problem.

Comment: Here is an answer to a similar problem that may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47047101/6287910

Answer (score 0):

use guideline-s (horizontal in the given case), on the center of the screen. that way you can attach the widget over there

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of share comments.

I found I just need to add constraintDimensionRatio, and then ImageView will scale with ratio, so app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias and app:layout_constraintVertical_bias will work fine!

```
app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:2.215"
```

## full codes

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_body"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:2.215"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/icon_body_w" />
```