# Can I have one imageView atop another while maitaining correct size and position?

Tags: android, image, android-studio, kotlin, imageview

[First image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyqRl.png)
[Image on top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MKjY.png)

Here's the xml code for these images:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:scaleX="1"
    android:scaleY="1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/include"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/include"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/room2" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="54dip"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:scaleX="0.20"
    android:scaleY="0.4"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
    tools:srcCompat="@drawable/typing1" />
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>`

The problem is that both of these have slightly different position and scale across different screen size's and it looks weird. Is there any way for them to match up perfectly?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "match up perfectly."

Comment: Like this: https://imgur.com/Vc3BzyW  on all devices. It looks ok on some screen sizes but offests by a few pixels on different ones.

Comment: I am going to point you to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47047101/6287910) I gave to a similar question a while back. It should help you out.